# Drivers for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I have CanoScan Lide 100 scanner and a Lexmark Z23 printer and I need to drivers for them. The problem is that I have Windows 10, and there are no drivers for this system for these products. What can I do?

Comment: At some point you will have to face reality: Obsolete hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Try Windows 8 drivers, and if those don't exist, try Windows 7.

Comment: If they don't work natively, after selecting the appropriate compatibility mode for the installation file, then they may work in a Virtual Machine of the appropriate type.

Comment: I tried drivers for Windows 8 and 7 and they didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried the *appropriate compatibility mode*?

Comment: What's it? How can I do it?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware-winpc/how-to-install-and-update-hardware-drivers-in/a97bbbd1-9973-4d66-9a5b-291300006293 <= Starts at "Using Compatibility Mode to Resolve Driver problems". Probably won't work either, your hardware is 20 years old! The scanner might (with Win8.1 drivers), forget about the printer.

Comment: The "compatibility mode" stuff doesn't work on anything but the installer. The compatibility "shims" are all in user mode. The actual driver code for most devices is in kernel mode and cannot be run in "compatibility mode".